# I have a build agent on my personal machine. Can I configure the agent capabilities to only build builds initiated by me and not other developers

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, build-agent, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I only want the agent I installed on my machine to build when I initiated the build.

Not sure how to set up the agent capabilities.

I want the agent to only run when I initiated the build.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I configure the agent capabilities to only build builds initiated by me and not other developers

You can set the Security of your build agent.

Go to `Project Settings`->`Agent pools`->Your private Agent->`Security`, and set all user except you with **Reader** Role:

[image]

With this setting, any other member could not see your private agent in the agent pool list when they queue build, only view it from Agent pools.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can set the [permissions/security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/permissions?view=azure-devops) for the pipelines to control the build triggers.
2. To use your own agent, set the [demand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/demands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to your agent name in the demand section of your pipelines as following - **agent.name** **equals** **YOUR_AGENT_NAME**.

Comment: If any other member also add above demand in their pipeline, so can he also use that agent?

Comment: Yes, he can use that agent too.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use agent pools: [Agent pools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/pools-queues?view=azure-devops)

1. Create your separate pool.([Creating agent pools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/pools-queues?view=azure-devops#creating-agent-pools))
2. Reconfigure your build agent to use your pool.
3. Update your build definition (or clone exiting) to use your pool.